# how can i let AsyncTask alive when activity cancel?

Tags: android, android-asynctask, stream

i am making an radio app and i want to keep the stream running when i change the activity ! i read that i can use service but its complex for me ! so i prefer to AsyncTask , how can i let AsyncTask alive when activity cancel ?

```
    static class Player extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Boolean> {
        @Override
        protected Boolean doInBackground(String... strings) {
            Boolean prepared = false;

            try {
                mediaPlayer.setDataSource(strings[0]);
                mediaPlayer.setOnCompletionListener(new MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mediaPlayer) {
                        Log.d("myTag", "This is my listnner");
                        initialStage = true;
                        playPause = false;
                        id_play.setImageResource(R.drawable.play);
                        mediaPlayer.stop();
                        mediaPlayer.reset();
                    }
                });

                mediaPlayer.prepare();
                prepared = true;

            } catch (Exception e) {
//                Log.e("MyAudioStreamingApp", e.getMessage());
                prepared = false;
            }

            return prepared;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Boolean aBoolean) {
            super.onPostExecute(aBoolean);

            if (progressDialog.isShowing()) {
                progressDialog.cancel();
            }

            mediaPlayer.start();
            initialStage = true;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();

            progressDialog.setMessage("Buffering...");
            progressDialog.show();
        }
    }
```

Comment: *i can use service but its complex for me ! so i prefer to AsyncTask* use a service anyway

Comment: Asynktask  works on Main thread. You have to use Service.

Comment: AsyncTask is binded to the Activity, simply is not the right choice for what you want to achieve

Answer (score 0):

This is a really bad approach. An `AsyncTask` is meant for short living processes. It is not suited for the `MediaPlayer` since you also want to pause, stop, resume and restart things. Also from a usability aspect you want to have a status bar of your MediaPlayer in the lock-screen or recent activity list.

With that in mind you have to use a `Service` and in this case a foreground service is the way to go. There is also a good android developer guide for it.

https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/media/mediaplayer.html